# How to parse excel files generated using Crystal Reports in C#

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have multiple excel files generated using Crystal Reports. I want to read the contents (cell values) of the file and display it on my UI in the form of html table. However, I am unable to parse the files as it mentions that the files are not BIFF8 compliant and throws exception when trying to read the file.

I have tried using the following API's so far: NPOI, NExcel, Gembox.Spreadsheets, OpenXML, Excelwriter, to parse those excel files, but nothing works.

Can someone suggest other APIs to parse such? Or any other alternative of how I can parse them?

Comment: "I have multiple excel files generated using Crystal Reports" - *exactly* what format are they in? Did you produce them, or are they from a third party? Are they really just plain-text HTML tables with and "xls" file extension? If you try opening one in a text editor what do you see?

Comment: What do you mean plain-text HTML tables?? These are crystal reports exported to excel from third party and have .xls as file extension. When I view them in text editor, most of the content is encoded but I can see the column headers and column data.

Comment: Do they open in excel with no error?

Comment: Yes I can view them in excel. No errors.

Comment: If you open the file in (eg) notepad does it look like plain text, or is it a "real" Excel file ?  The fact that none of the other libraries you tried can read the files suggests they are either corrupt/malformed or not actually native xls format.

Comment: Only the column headers and content are plain text. Rest all seem to be encoded. This is the exception I get when I try parsing such file - "does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry. Is it really an excel file?" I dont know whether the files are BIFF8 compatible as I can view them in excel without any errors.

Comment: Hard to tell more without seeing a file - can you share one via (eg) dropbox or some other hosting site?